# How do i show my data from a table with specific position to a combobox? example is this

Tags: vb.net, combobox

How do i show my data from a table in database with specific position to a combobox? example is this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FFwH.png)

Only with the President Position candidates will appear on combobox1 from table1
Only with the VPresident Position candidates will appear on combobox2 from table1
and so on...

im stuck with this on combobox1 which is called prescombo
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1WZl.png)

```
Private Sub prescombo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prescombo.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE Position = President"
            Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EXPOOKY;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=True")
                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, con)
                    Dim datapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim datable As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    datapter.Fill(datable)
                    prescombo.DisplayMember = "CandidateName"
                    prescombo.ValueMember = "CandidateID"
                    If datable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        If datable.Rows(3)("Position") = "President" Then
                            presparty.Text = datable.Rows(3).Item("Position").ToString
                        End If
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

This is what i tried based on my logic and its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're filtering the data using a `WHERE` clause in the query then there's no need to check the records in the result set. Just populate the `DataTable` and bind it.

```vb
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE Position = 'President'"
Dim connectionString = "Data Source=EXPOOKY;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=True"

Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)

    With prescombo
        .DisplayMember = "CandidateName"
        .ValueMember = "CandidateID"
        .DataSource = table
    Endf With
End Using
```